# How to autopopulate an if/elif block from a list of values?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I am working on a function that allows a user to provide a list of values which will then autopopulate an `if`/`elif` block. For example, here is an example of the `if`/`elif` block that I am trying to autopopulate with `acres_list`:

```
acres_list = [15, 20, 25, 35, 45]

if acres <= 15:
    return 1
elif 20 >= acres >15:
    return 2
elif 25 >= acres > 20:
    return 3       
elif 35 >= acres > 25:
    return 4     
elif 45 >= acres > 35:
    return 5     
elif acres > 45:
    return 6
```

I could provide a pointer to a specific list value like so:

```
acres = 17.46 # Some value to test. The function should return `2`
acres_list = [15, 20, 25, 35, 45]
    
def find_acres(acres, acres_list):
    if acres <= acres_list[0]:
        return 1
    elif acres_list[1] >= acres >acres_list[0]:
        return 2
    elif acres_list[2] >= acres > acres_list[1]:
        return 3       
    elif acres_list[3] >= acres > acres_list[2]:
        return 4     
    elif acres_list[4] >= acres > acres_list[3]:
        return 5     
    elif acres > acres_list[4]:
        return 6
```

However, this would fail if the user provided a list such as:

```
acres_list = [15, 20, 25, 35, 45, 50, 60, 70, 120]
```

or

```
acres_list = [5, 10, 15]
```

What approach can I take to autopopulate an `if`/`else` block with a variable sized list of values?

Comment: What's `acres`?

Comment: Thanks for catching that @U11-Forward. I have corrected the example to include reference to `acres`. It is essentially a value to test. In this case `acres = 17.46` should return a value of `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bisect module to efficiently search for a position in an ordered list:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def find_acres(a, L):
    return bisect_left(L,a)+1

acres = 17.46 # Some value to test. The function should return `2`
acres_list = [15, 20, 25, 35, 45]

find_acres(10,acres_list)    # 1 
find_acres(17.46,acres_list) # 2   
find_acres(35,acres_list)    # 4
find_acres(100,acres_list)   # 6
```

Comment: `find_acres(100, acres_list)` returning 6 is unusual, that is outside of the index range. Any thought on what is going on there?

Comment: Since the values are inclusive up to their respective positions, going beyond 45 (position 5) gets a value of 6.  That's also what the if/elif structure would give since 100 is > 45.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generalize the process.  Write a loop to walk through the values by index.  You return the index of the first value that is greater than your target `acres`.

```
for idx in range(len(acres_list)):
    if acres < acres_list[idx]:
        break
#  At this point, idx is your needed value
```

That is the basic structure.  You need to check whether this works for a value less or greater than any in the list.

Can you finish from here?

Also look up the `enumerate` function; this will make your code a little nicer.

Comment: You can just use `return idx` instead of `break`

Comment: Yes.  I'm trying to leave various bits of work for OP.  :-)

Comment: Wow, you still haven't thrown those rose-colored glasses in the trash.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that the return values could be anything, I just chose 1-n for this example. `return idx` might not work if the return values are not sequential @Barmar.

Comment: If your return values are something else, then make a second list from those.  Use `idx` to access the return value.

Comment: Or use a list of tuples with the acres and return values.